# Custom Footer Covering the Text Input when keyboard popsup React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am very new with React native and just trying with an app for my church where members can register.

Here is the [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@sforsandeep/ioc-cms?platform=android)

Here I have a multiline textbox for address. But its causing some problem with IOS and Android.

In IOS, the footer is not making any trouble. But content is not scrolling up or I have no idea what we are typing in the input

[image]

But in Android, the problem causing is from Footer

When we start focusing on that multiline textbox for entry, the keyboard pops up, but the Footer also moves up and hides the input area.

[image]

After some search I found there is some wrapper like ScrollView.

So I wrapped my view in layout page which holds the components like this

```
  <ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.content}>{children}</View>
  </ScrollView>
```

But that hiding the registration page completely for Android and I can see some top portions of Registration page in IOS.

[image]

Please help

Comment: I think you have added flex: 1 in your root component of the screen, If yes, try to give height: '100%'

Answer (score 0):

Please add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your `android:name=".MainActivity"`

in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Could you please share little more details

Comment: @SandeepThomas just try thing and run your app , it will take your footer above the keyboard of device